# Traversing XML in nested for loop VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am experimenting with XML in VB.net and I am having trouble getting a nested for loop to work.

Here's a snippet of the XML:

```
<CustomDirectory>
  <CustomGroup>
    <Members>
      <Member>User1</Member>
      <Member>User2</Member>
      .
      .
    </Members>
  </CustomGroup>
  <Name>Some name</Name>
</CustomDirectory>
```

I am using the following code to traverse the groups and output it to a RichTextBox

```
Dim xmlRoot As XElement = XElement.Load(xmlPath_var)

Dim populatedGroups As IEnumerable(Of XElement) =
        From el In xmlRoot.<CustomGroup>
        Where el.<Members>.<Member>.Count > 1
        Select el

For i = 0 To populatedGroups.Count - 1
        If xmlCodeGenerator_bg.CancellationPending = True Then
            e.Cancel = True
            Exit For
        Else
            output.AppendText(vbTab & "<CustomGroup>" & vbNewLine)
            output.AppendText(vbTab & vbTab & "<Members>" & vbNewLine)
            For ie = 0 To populatedGroups.<Members>.<Member>.Count - 1
                output.AppendText(vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "<Member>" & populatedGroups.<Members>.<Member>.ElementAt(ie).Value & "</Member>" & vbNewLine)
            Next
            output.AppendText(vbTab & vbTab & "</Members>" & vbNewLine)
            output.AppendText(vbTab & vbTab & "<Name>" & populatedGroups.ElementAt(i).<Name>.Value & "</Name>" & vbNewLine)
            output.AppendText(vbTab & "</CustomGroup>" & vbNewLine)
        End If
        xmlCodeGenerator_bg.ReportProgress(i)
    Next
```

My problem is that the output shows the same members for both groups in my file, and those members belong to the last group. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Perhaps `For ie = 0 To populatedGroups.ElementAt(i).<Members>.<Member>.Count - 1`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Code below will produce a 2 dimension array

```css
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim input As String = _
        "<CustomDirectory>" & _
          "<CustomGroup>" & _
            "<Members>" & _
              "<Member>User1</Member>" & _
              "<Member>User2</Member>" & _
            "</Members>" & _
          "</CustomGroup>" & _
          "<CustomGroup>" & _
            "<Members>" & _
              "<Member>User3</Member>" & _
              "<Member>User4</Member>" & _
            "</Members>" & _
          "</CustomGroup>" & _
          "<CustomGroup>" & _
            "<Members>" & _
              "<Member>User5</Member>" & _
              "<Member>User6</Member>" & _
            "</Members>" & _
          "</CustomGroup>" & _
          "<CustomGroup>" & _
            "<Members>" & _
              "<Member>User7</Member>" & _
              "<Member>User8</Member>" & _
            "</Members>" & _
          "</CustomGroup>" & _
          "<Name>Group A</Name>" & _
        "</CustomDirectory>"

        Dim cD As XElement = XElement.Parse(input)

        Dim results = cD.Descendants("CustomGroup").Select(Function(x) New With { _
              .members = x.Descendants("Member").Select(Function(y) New With {.member = CType(y, String)}).ToList()}).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
​
```